# How to compute the gradient of a signal?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a signal u and I used the following code to compute the gradient:
`gradx_u = [diff(u,1,1);zeros(1,size(u,2))]; grady_u = [diff(u,1,2) zeros(size(u,1),1)];`
The problem is that I receive a zero vector for gradx_u. For example if I take the vector [0.1 0.22 0.3 0.5] as u, I receive:`gradx_u = [ 0 0 0 0] grady_u = [0.1200 0.0800 0.2000 0]`
I really appreciate if it someone could please help me with this problem.

Comment: Can you have both an `x` and `y` gradient of a 1D signal? I assume the signal you referring to is in the spatial domain. `diff(u,1,1)` will return zero since there are no vertical neighbours to compare to/use to take the derivative.

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, the signal is in the spatial domain. That is true. There is no vertical component so I receive zero for gradx. Thank you.